# Minify - Composer install error

Tags: php, composer-php, minify

I am trying to install from a `composer.json` file using `composer install` in the right directory but I am getting this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package scrapbook/psr-cache could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package satooshi/php-coveralls dev-master exists as satooshi/php-coveralls[0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 1.0.x-dev, 1.1.x-dev, 2.0.x-dev, v0.6.0, v0.6.1, v0.7.0, v0.7.1, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0, v2.0.0] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

Comment: either this package removed or directory name changed at composer packages.

Comment: Could you share your `composer.json`?

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems:
1) There isn't any package named `scrapbook/psr-cache` inside packagist
2) `satooshi/php-coveralls` hasn't a valid version into your composer.json

I advise you to change the package psr-cache with one valid and fix the php-coveralls version

The composer error is very clear in this.

If you want to check for all valid package please refer to this:

[Packagist](https://packagist.org)